# SHDocVw.dll reference not used in exe

Tags: c#, dll, reference

I have a problem when I use my executable file instead of debugging it in Visual Studio 2010.

I want to get the url of a youtube video from a tab in IE, and I made a reference to: `C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll` and also to "Microsoft Internet Controls" in the COM tab (even though the program works fine without this reference in debugging mode).

The dll that is referenced is in the Debug folder and is called "Interop.SHDocVw.dll".
Here is a part of my code:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    { //the foreach loop isn't executed when I use the executable file
        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in new SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass())
        {
            url = ieInst.LocationURL;
            if (url.Contains("youtube"))
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("youtube-url").SetAttribute("value", url);
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
                usable = url;
                timer1.Start();
            }

        }

    }
```

When I run this in debugging mode in Visual Studio it all works fine but when i use the executable file it doesn't work and the DocumentCompleted happens multiple times.

Any help?

Comment: There's no need to put the `C#` tag in your title, since it has already been tagged. Read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for more details.

Comment: There's no point in using ShellWindows here, and it is likely to fail since it also returns Windows Explorer instances.  You already have the URL, it is available as the e.Url property.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to check the WebBrowser.ReadyState property within your DocumentCompleted method. Something along the lines:

```
if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    DoWork();
}
```

Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserreadystate.aspx